# App freezes when loading list items from API by pull down SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: xamarin, swiperefreshlayout

It's a new challenge for me but never solved yet.I hope anyone can help me to pass this painful and timesucker.

I used Listview to show items from my web service and to refresh list data SwipeRefreshLayout is the one option for me.

When I pulldown SwipeRefresh , list items refreshed but App freezes to completely load data and indicator of SwipeRefreshLayout not move .What's the solution?

The code is here:

```cs
ApiDataManager.ApiDAl apiDAl=new ApiDataManager.ApiDAl();
private DrawerLayout _drawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle _barDrawer;
private ListView listview;
private PodCastAdapter _podCastAdapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout _swipeRefresh;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
    var _toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    _drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.leftDrawer);
    SetSupportActionBar(_toolbar);
    SupportActionBar.Title = "Some";


    //Swipe Refresh
    _swipeRefresh = FindViewById<SwipeRefreshLayout>(Resource.Id.swipeRefresh);
    _swipeRefresh.Refresh += _swipeRefresh_Refresh;



    _barDrawer = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, _drawer, _toolbar, 0, 1);
    SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);


    listview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.EslTitles);    

   //Get list data by webservice backend
    _podCastAdapter = new PodCastAdapter(this);
    listview.Adapter = _podCastAdapter;

    listview.ItemClick += Listview_ItemClick;
}

private void _swipeRefresh_Refresh(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   //Get list data by last received
    listview.Adapter = _podCastAdapter;

    BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();              
    worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;               
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    _swipeRefresh.Refreshing = false;
    Toast.MakeText(this, "refreshing false", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}

private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     //Get list data by webservice backend
    _podCastAdapter = new PodCastAdapter(this);
    listview.Adapter = _podCastAdapter;
}
```

Main AXML code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/leftDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--Main Content-->
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefresh"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content">
          <FrameLayout
               android:id="@+id/container"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ListView
               android:minWidth="25px"
               android:minHeight="25px"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:id="@+id/EslTitles" />
          </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <!--Left Navigation Drawer-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llLeftDrawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="?attr/colorAccent"
            android:layout_gravity="left">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem, because you call UI element in nonUI-thread. Move

```
 listview.Adapter = _podCastAdapter;
```

to

> Worker_RunWorkerCompleted

this method synchronized with UI-thread

Comment: Thanks @helsq , I moved  listview.Adapter = _podCastAdapter; to Worker_RunWorkerCompleted method but never fixed my problem.

Comment: And it throw me in an Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Observer android.widget.AbsListView$AdapterDataSetObserver@37c7bafe was not registered.

Comment: This is different problem. You don't have to re-create a **PodCatAdatper**, you have to update data in it. Example before: 
`public PodCastAdapter(Context context){
 //init
 //load data
}`
after:
`public PodCastAdapter(Context context){
 //init
}

public void LoadData(){
 //load data
}
`

and in Worker_DoWork you will call **_podCastAdapter.LoadData()** and in RunWorkerCompleted **_podCastAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged()**